# slow apache access on virtualbox 4.2

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos5

I am using virtualbox 4.2 with guest addition for sharing folders between my host windows 7 64 bit and guest centos 5.

I am running apache on my guest centos which access shared folders.

We are planning to use this set up for our developers locally.

But When i try to open localhost on my windows 7 browser it takes several seconds (around 30) to respond.It is really frustrating to develop and test with this setup.

Any help on improving the performance of shared folder is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of VBOX being slow is being starved for memory and then caching.  You should probably have a host machine with 4GB and configure the linux guest for at least 2GB

Second problem to consider might be your virtual networking setup - the defaults in VBOX should be ok but maybe you are routing somewhere and this is taking time - take a look at route on the Centos guest
HTH
DAnny